# how to run multiple instances of a local zimserver in python

Tags: python, python3

I downloaded offline zim archives of websites such as `wikipedia.com`, `stackoverflow.com`, `unix.stackexchange.com` etc. and serve them via below script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import subprocess
import sys
import threading 
from zimply import ZIMServer
ZIMServer("/home/user/zim/wikipedia_en_all_novid_2018-05.zim", index_file="/home/user/zim/wikipedia_en_all_novid_2018-05.idx", port=8790, encoding="utf-8")
```

it works well but when I add another line

```
 ZIMServer("/home/user/zim/math.stackexchange.com_eng_all_2018-08.zim",  index_file="/home/user/zim/math.stackexchange.com_eng_all_2018-08.idx", port=7890, encoding="utf-8")
```

it doesn't load the second `ZIMServer`. I think it's a python multithreading issue. How can I run both of them in the single script?